# What is the role of the sulfuric acid in a titration between potassium permaganate and iron ammonium sulphate solution?

Tags: acid-base, redox, titration

So basically my titration was of finding the concentration of potassium permaganate against an iron ammonium solution. In the iron ammonium sulphate solution it consisted of water, iron ammonium sulfate and sulfuric acid. Im not sure about the role of sulfuric acid in this case so if someone could explain it to me that'd be great!

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67272/potassium-permanganate-iron-sulfate-titration-didnt-work-and-i-cant-work-out

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67753/potassium-permanganate-to-analyze-iron-compounds

Comment: And this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32750/minimising-the-formation-of-manganese-dioxide-in-the-titration-of-potassium-perm more or less answers it